# How to remove the list index out of range?

Tags: index-error

The code runs perfectly with the custom input but while running in competetive programming platform, it shows runtime error.

I have searched about this but couldn't resolve it.

```
def GCD(num1, num2):

    if num1 < num2:
        small = num1
    else:
        small = num2

    for i in range(1, small + 1):
        if (num1 % i == 0) and (num2 % i == 0):
            gcd = i

    return gcd

arr = [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]
print(GCD(arr[0], arr[1]))
```

Runtime Error
Traceback (most recent call last): File Main.py , line 10, in  print(GCD(arr[0], arr[1])) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Do you always give two numbers separated by space in the input?

Comment: yes i provide two numbers with spaces in the input.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line you are printing the GCD of the first and the second element of the array which are of the index 0 and 1. But if user only enters a single number then index 1 is out of range. So you can just check if the size of array is less than two then simply print the element at the index 0.

```
if len(arr) is 1:
    print(arr[0])
else:
    print(GCD(arr[0], arr[1]))
```

Furthermore, if you are trying to find the GCD of the array then the algorithm is wrong. You will have to iterate over the array and find the GCD.

```
if len(arr) is 1:
    print(arr[0])
else:
    answer = arr[0];
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        answer = GCD(answer,arr[i])
    print(answer)
```